# adding style to items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing a madlibs-type program. Prompts ask for words, which are then added to a string. I would like the words used from the prompts to be underlined when they are displayed with the rest of the string. I have created an array with all the prompts. Now, I just need to know how to run through that array and change the text-decoration to "underline". I know I need to use a for-loop through the array, but not sure of how to approach it.

What is the best way to make this happen?

```
HTML:

<body>
<div id = "story-space"> 
</div>
<script src = "madlibs.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var prompt1 = prompt("Enter a animal.");
var prompt2 = prompt("Enter a city.");
var prompt3 = prompt("Enter an activity.");

var prompts = [prompt1, prompt2, prompt3, prompt4];

var text = "There was once was a " + prompt1 + " from " + prompt2 + " who liked to "  + prompt3 + "."

document.getElementById("story-space").innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can you add the html style like this

```
  var text = "There was once was a <span style='text-decoration:underline'>" + prompt1 + "</span> from <span style='text-decoration:underline'>" + prompt2 + "</span> who liked to <span style='text-decoration:underline'>"  + prompt3 + "</span>."
```

Comment: I guess that's one way to do it, but I wanted to avoid all the repetition of that. Plus, I'm relatively new and trying to experiment with different ways of performing tasks.Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this by mapping all the prompts with an underline class.

```js
var prompt1 = prompt("Enter a animal.");
var prompt2 = prompt("Enter a city.");
var prompt3 = prompt("Enter an activity.");

var prompts = [prompt1, prompt2, prompt3];

prompts = prompts.map(prompt => `<span class="underline">${prompt}</span>`)

var text = "There was once was a " + prompts[0] + " from " + prompts[1] + " who liked to "  + prompts[1] + "."

document.getElementById("story-space").innerHTML = text;
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id = "story-space"> 
</div>
```

You can also try something like below where you just provide the pre-text for your prompt and let the `Map` and `Reduce` do the rest of the job for you.

```js
let textPromptMap = new Map();

textPromptMap.set("There was once was a ", prompt("Enter a animal."))

textPromptMap.set(" from ", prompt("Enter a city."))

textPromptMap.set(" who liked to  ", prompt("Enter an activity."))

const text = [...textPromptMap.keys()]
              .reduce((a, b) => 
                `${a}${b}<span class="underline">${textPromptMap.get(b)}</span>`, ""
               )

document.getElementById("story-space").innerHTML = text;
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id = "story-space"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Could not get this to work. Does the use of the dollar signs mean you're using jquery here? I'm a bit new to these concepts. Will look into mapping, though. Thank you.

Comment: The dollar symbols are the newly introduced template literals in ES6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals. You should be able to execute it by running the code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

one simple way you can do it it as follows, note that you need to check for empty strings returned from prompt though, which is not handled in this answer,

```
var questions = ['an animal', 'a city', 'an activity'],
    answers = [];

// create source string with placeholders that 
// can be replaced with values in from prompts
var sourceText = "There was once was a {0} from {1} who liked to {2}."

//loop thru questions array and store answers in 'answers' variable
for (var q = 0; q < questions.length; q++) {

    //create answer as span element
    var question = questions[q],
        answer = '<span style="text-decoration:underline;">';        

    answer += prompt('Enter ' + question);
    answer +='</span>';

    //update source text's 'qth' placeholder with answer
    sourceText = sourceText.replace( new RegExp( "\\{" + q + "\\}", "g" ), function() {
        return answer;
    });
}

//update the target element's innerHTML
document.getElementById("story-space").innerHTML = sourceText;
```